# Unable to move mouse cursor in Antd input when using react DND

Tags: antd, react-dnd

I have an Antd accordion with inputs in it which are movable/draggable using React-dnd.

The problem that I am having is when using Firefox, I can't move the text cursor/pointer in the Input field with a mouse. But this works fine for other browsers.

There is a similar issue been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64873010/ant-design-input-react-dnd-unable-to-move-text-pointer-inside-ant-design-inp?newreg=7ff19d94a64f4f4db00665224edafd1e) but there is no solution provided.

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680363/prevent-drag-event-to-interfere-with-input-elements-in-firefox-using-html5-drag) that there is a known issue with html5 draggable elements in firefox.

Can anyone please share some insight here to how to fix this?